# Nodes with physicsBody.mass = 0 stacking on main node is affecting main node's jump height

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a game where there is a main `playerSprite` that jumps every time I click on the screen.  Every few moments, a `fattySprite` node falls from the sky to stack on top of the `playerSprite`.  With each additional node stacking, the jump height is reduced.  Why is the jump height being reduced? I've tried setting all sorts of physicsBody properties to 0 in the `fattySprite` nodes in an attempt to prevent these extra nodes from affecting the jump height.

Code snippets:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        // Character creation
        self.playerSprite = PlayerNode(position: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 9, y: self.frame.size.height / 4),
                                       size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 5, height: self.frame.size.height / 10))
        self.playerSprite?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
        self.playerSprite?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | trapCategory
        self.playerSprite?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        self.playerSprite?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
        self.playerSprite?.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        self.addChild(self.playerSprite!)
        self.playerSprite?.beginAnimation()

        // Fatties spawning
        let wait_fatty = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3, withRange: 2)
        let spawnFatty = SKAction.run({
            let fattySprite = PlayerNode(position: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 9, y: self.frame.size.height),
                                         size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 5, height: self.frame.size.height / 10))
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = self.fattiesCategory
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = self.fattiesCategory | self.playerCategory
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.mass = 0
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
            fattySprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0
            self.addChild(fattySprite)

        })
        let fattySequence = SKAction.sequence([wait_fatty, spawnFatty])
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(fattySequence))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if self.playerSprite?.action(forKey: "jump") == nil { // check that there's no jump action running
            //self.playerSprite?.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 500 )
            self.playerSprite?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 500))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a physicsbody before giving values to it. 
In all of these calls to fattySprite.physicsbody? you are trying to assign values to a nil variable.

Do this: 
    fattySprite.physicsbody = SKPhysicsbody(rectangleOf: fattySprite.size)

and then assign all physical properties. I cannot see how you built your playernode, there might be more appropiate physicsbody-init functions. Check the docs :) 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody